# Nette Forms Validation - how to set field not required?

Tags: php, forms, validation, nette

I add text inputs into a form and add them some rules.
These inputs are not required, but if I do not fill these fields, I get a validation error.

Example:

```
$this->addText('operationID', 'Operation ID:')
    ->setAttribute('class', 'tf tf-w110px')
    ->addRule(Nutnet_Form::INTEGER, 'Operation ID must be integer');
```

How to properly set rule, that would accept not filled `operationID` field, instead of giving `Operation ID must be integer` error?

Using `conditions` helps, but it is not comfortable.

Comment: default INTEGER validation requires valid number. NULL, empty string, etc. is not a valid integer.

Answer (score 7):

Using condition is the correct way. Why do you think it's not comfortable?

```
$this->addText('operationID', 'Operation ID:')
    ->setAttribute('class', 'tf tf-w110px')
    ->addCondition(Nutnet_Form::FILLED)
        ->addRule(Nutnet_Form::INTEGER, 'Operation ID must be integer');
```